# 1С 8.3. БП3. Как программно реализовать пакетную печатную печать для конкретного документа (разные макеты)?

Tags: 1с

Нужно при нажатии отдельной кнопки "печать" сделать печать нескольких макетов для конкретного

документа. Например, есть макет "Зарплата" (2 экземпляра), и макет "Счета" (3 экземпляра).

Нашел такой простенький код:

```
СсылкаНаОбъект.ПолучитьОбъект().Печать("Зарплата", 2, Истина); //2 экземпляра макета "Зарплата" 
СсылкаНаОбъект.ПолучитьОбъект().Печать("Счета", 3, Истина); //3 экземпляра макета "Счета"
```

Но здесь после выбора документа выходит `ошибка метода "печать"` (пишет что такого метода не

существует).

Нашел второй, более длинный код:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ПакетнаяПечатьНаСервере(Пакет)
    ОбработкаОбъект = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Объект");
    
    СхемаКомпоновкиДанных = ОбработкаОбъект.ПолучитьМакет("Зарплата");
    // Получим настройки по умолчанию.
    Настройки = СхемаКомпоновкиДанных.НастройкиПоУмолчанию;
    // Сформируем макет компоновки данных.
    КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;
    МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных, Настройки);
    // Выполним компоновку данных.
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновки);
    // Выведем результат компоновки в табличный документ.
    ДокументРезультат = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьДокумент(ДокументРезультат);
    ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных);
    
    СхемаКомпоновкиДанных = ОбработкаОбъект.ПолучитьМакет("Счета");
    // Получим настройки по умолчанию.
    Настройки = СхемаКомпоновкиДанных.НастройкиПоУмолчанию;
    // Сформируем макет компоновки данных.
    КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;
    МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных, Настройки);
    // Выполним компоновку данных.
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновки);
    // Выведем результат компоновки в табличный документ.
    ДокументРезультат1 = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьДокумент(ДокументРезультат1);
    ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных);

    Пакет = Новый ПакетОтображаемыхДокументов;
    // Документы, находящиеся в этом пакете, печатаются в 2 экземплярах
    Пакет.КоличествоЭкземпляров = 2;
    // Добавляем документы в пакет
    ЭлементПакета1 = Пакет.Состав.Добавить();
    ЭлементПакета1.Данные = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(ДокументРезультат, 

УникальныйИдентификатор);
    
    // Добавляем вложенный пакет для третьего документа
    ВложенныйПакет = Новый ПакетОтображаемыхДокументов;
    // Документ во вложенном пакете печатается в 3 экземплярах
    ВложенныйПакет.КоличествоЭкземпляров = 3;
    // Добавляем документ во вложенный пакет
    ЭлементВложенногоПакета1 = ВложенныйПакет.Состав.Добавить();
    ЭлементВложенногоПакета1.Данные = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(ДокументРезультат1, 

УникальныйИдентификатор);
    
    ЭлементПакета2 = Пакет.Состав.Добавить();
    ЭлементПакета2.Данные = ВложенныйПакет;

    
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПакетнаяПечать(Команда)
    Пакет = Неопределено;
    ПакетнаяПечатьНаСервере(Пакет);
    Пакет.Напечатать();
КонецПроцедуры
```

Здесь тоже выходит ошибка: `"Недопустимое значение параметра (параметр номер '1')`".

Как правильно реализовать печать нескольких макетов для конкретного документа?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка скорее всего на строке:

```
ОбработкаОбъект = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Объект");
```

Чтобы исправить конкретно эту ошибку наберите строку:

```
ОбработкаОбъект = РеквизитФормыВЗначение
```

затем **(** после чего 1С сама предложит Вам правильное-возможное значение // может Отчет // выберите это значение, завершите редактирование строки и попробуйте ...